# AngularJS: How do I select object field when using ui-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I want to convert this HTML select to [angular-ui/ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) syntax:

```
<select ng-model="person.email" ng-options="p.email as p.name for p in people"></select>
```

How can i make the ng-model be the persons email? The ng-options syntax ("p.email as p.name for p in people") does not work with the ui-select repeat.

I've managed to make the ui-select choose the right person object. But I'm just interested in the email field.

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.email" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people">
      <div ng-bind-html="person.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

People object in controller:

```
$scope.people = [
    { name: 'Adam',      email: 'adam@email.com',      age: 10 },
    { name: 'Amalie',    email: 'amalie@email.com',    age: 12 }
];
```

Demo of above code: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X6eg70?p=preview)

Comment: [Angular chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) is better to handle those.. and syntax is closely aligned as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see that demo :http://plnkr.co/edit/InfxSo?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <p>Selected: {{person.email}}</p>
    <ui-select ng-model="$parent.person" theme="bootstrap">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Choose">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people">
            <div ng-bind-html="person.name"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- This is what i want to do -->
    <!--<select ng-model="person.email" ng-options="p.email as p.name for p in people">

          </select>>-->
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, this works if we change the model to ng-model="person.selected.email", but I want to bind the select directly to $scope.person.email

Comment: Thanks, @sss. The the ng-model="$parent.person" in your Plunker did the trick. Update the code in your answer and I will accept it as the solution.